# Prefab in Unity "loses" Collision Detection after transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a basic cube prefab and the collision detection works well.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

        Debug.Log ("Diram...");
        //onplatform = true;

    }
```

However, when I duplicate the prefab and change the position / rotation, 
the collider stops working and no collision events are fired.

I do not want to use triggers since the objects lose all collisions and the game stops working.

Any advice here?

Comment: So where is the code that duplicates the prefab?

Comment: Here it is as txt file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2nsba75qmg0k9f/code.txt?dl=0  It basically creates a zig zag type of lane with cube objects like here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx7v82xx8dptml4/Screenshot%202016-04-07%2007.07.32.png?dl=0

Comment: Not everyone uses dropbox. Please paste the code of your text file on the question itself.

Comment: @NahuelIanni The code is long. You don't have to download it. Just click on the link and you can read it on Dropbox website. It is long to post here.

Comment: Uuh...@Programmer, you shouldn't be encouraging members to post code off-site, especially if it might contain pertinent information. The correct approach in cases when the code is too lengthy to post here, is to narrow down the problem code with debugging so the original question contains everything necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was able to find a solution to the problem by looking outside the box, so this specific collision detection is not obligatory for the game. Thanks for the effort anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

**1** Change:

```
Rigidbody obj1 = ....
Rigidbody rb1 = obj1.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
obj1.transform.position = newPos;
```

to

```
Rigidbody obj1 = ....
Rigidbody rb1 = obj1.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
obj1.transform.position = newPos;
rb1.MovePosition(newPos+transform.forward);
```

**2** Make sure that `isKinematic` is set to `false` after you instantiate the prefab.

```
rb1.isKinematic = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try it and let you know if it works!